# How can i change htmlhelper dropdownlist to kendo ui dropdownlist without using html.kendio().dropdownlist()?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui, html-helper

I use htmlhelper dropdownlist in my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GroupID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Groups, "Choose...",
new { id = "GroupsDropDown" })

ViewBag.Groups= new SelectList(db.Groups.ToList(), "GroupID", "GroupName");
```

I have 2 questions:
1- how can I change Html.DropDownListFor() to Kendo dropDown without using "Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(...) using jquery?
 I used the code bellow, but it doesn't work :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("[id$='DropDown']").kendoDropDownList();
</script>
```

2- Is it true that i use ViewBags for filling my dropdowns ,...? Is there any better way that i can use instead of viewbag ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the selector that you tried actually returns the DropDownList.

Did you try to use

```
$('#GroupID').kendoDropDownList();
```

Using ViewBag is just fine.

Comment: Should be $("#GroupsDropDown") I believe.

Comment: Thanks for helping but i have many html.dropdownlistfor() and i want to change them together with one jquery code in my layout.

Comment: Add CSS class to them and then use the jQuery class selector. For example if you add class 'foo', then you can use $('.foo').kendoDropDownList({...})

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery select does not look right.  Should be $("#GroupsDropDown").
As for your second question, I prefer to bind to an IEnumerable.  I typically have this as a property on my model if I don't cache the items.  If I am caching, I put them in a ReferenceData class.(e.g. model.ReferenceData.MyDropDownListItems)  There's an overload for @Html.DropDownListFor that will take this, or you can use Kendo's .BindTo method if you use Kendo.